# Polynomial root to integer

Tags: r

I've got `[1] -5+0i` from `polyroot(l)` function and I don't understand how I can print it like -5. And why `row.names=F, col.names=F` doesn't work?

```
l <- c(5, 1)
x <- polyroot(l)
ans <- data.frame(sum(x), prod(x))
print(ans, row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

Here I need to print `-5 -5`, but I've got:

```
 sum.x. prod.x.
  -5+0i   -5+0i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the name attributes and take out the real part by:

```
attributes(ans) <- NULL
sapply(ans, Re)
```

Comment: Hi! I've got an error: `Error in Re(ans) : non-numeric argument to function`.

Comment: I updated my answer to also work with `data.frame`s.

Comment: Sorry, but I've got `[1] -5 -5`

Comment: Is the problem the `[1]`? You can just print the content of the vector `cat(sapply(ans, Re))`

Comment: Because I'm novice in R. Thank you so much!